# Setting a character limit on an Input field(using react-contenteditable) not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I am using react-contenteditable library to show an input value.
I want to limit the character which can be typed in to 50 char.
I have tried slice and substring and even checking the length of string but nothing is limiting and even the 51st and so on character in shown in the input box. Also if I use slice or substring after 50th character if I press space button then an & symbol is attached to rest of the string and the application seems to get stuck.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dhawan-hbk1w2?file=/src/index.js

Above is link to the code

```
import React  from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";
import "./styles.css";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.contentEditable = React.createRef();
    this.state = {html: "<b>Hello <i>World</i></b>"};
  };

  handleChange = evt => {
    console.log(evt.target.value.length)
// if( evt.target.value.length <= 50){
//   this.setState({html: evt.target.value});
// }
this.setState({html: evt.target.value.slice(0,50)});
 
  };

  render = () => {
    return <ContentEditable
              innerRef={this.contentEditable}
              html={this.state.html} // innerHTML of the editable div
              disabled={false}       // use true to disable editing
              onChange={this.handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
             
            />
  };
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, rootElement);

``
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
handleChange = evt => {
    if(evt.target.value.length > 50){
        return
    }
    
    this.setState({html: evt.target.value});
};
```

Comment: After 50 function will return , but still I can see the character in input box. Any idea how can I avoid that